# Logo on navbar is not displaying

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I am creating a website with the react.js framework and am very new to it. I am trying to get my logo on the bootstrap navbar. However, it seems that the image is not displaying.

This is the code for my navigation bar

```
<nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark fixed-top bg-dark" id="mainNav">
            <div className="container">
                <a className="navbar-brand js-scroll-trigger" href="#page-top"><img src="navbar-logo.svg" alt="" /></a>
                <button className="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    Menu
                    <i className="fas fa-bars ml-1"></i>
                </button>
                <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
                    <ul className="navbar-nav text-uppercase ml-auto">
                        <li className="nav-item"><a className="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#services">Services</a></li>
                        <li className="nav-item"><a className="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#portfolio">Facilities</a></li>
                        <li className="nav-item"><a className="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#about">About</a></li>
                        <li className="nav-item"><a className="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#team">Executives</a></li>
                        <li className="nav-item"><a className="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to import image. You can't add src like this in react:

Do this:

1. Import logo

```
import myLogo from 'navbar-logo.svg';
```

2. Add logo src:

```
<img src={myLogo} alt="" />

...your rest of code
```

Comment: the compiler is telling me that the image can't be resolved when it is in the same directory as my app.js

Comment: You need to set path. from where you are importing. Where is your image placed? Something like this : `./navbar-logo.svg` if its placed in same folder

Comment: nvm now it works. I just added ./ to the path. thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show logo you must use html tag :

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
     <link media rel="icon" href="##your logo url" type="image/png" />
    </head>
    <body>
    ##content
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```css
.logo {
  height:25px;
}
```

```html
<nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark fixed-top bg-dark" id="mainNav">
            <div className="container">
                <a className="navbar-brand js-scroll-trigger" href="#page-top"><img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/1029/4887/2759.jpg?hmac=uMSExsgG8_PWwP9he9Y0LQ4bFDLlij7voa9lU9KMXDE" alt="" class="logo"/></a>
                <button className="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    Menu
                    <i className="fas fa-bars ml-1"></i>
                </button>
                <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
                    <ul className="navbar-nav text-uppercase ml-auto">
                        <li className="nav-item"><a className="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#services">Services</a></li>
                        <li className="nav-item"><a className="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#portfolio">Facilities</a></li>
                        <li className="nav-item"><a className="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#about">About</a></li>
                        <li className="nav-item"><a className="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#team">Executives</a></li>
                        <li className="nav-item"><a className="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
```

if you want to use a local image, import from your project and pass to src

```
import Logo from './path_name';
```

pass like this.

```
<img src={Logo} alt="" class="logo"/>
```